# Disable editing account info

Tags: users, policykit, accounts

I have a public desktop running ubuntu 14.04 with a public account (no guest account). People can change the full name of the user through the user accounts GUI. Is there any way to block this?

I already set `CHFN_RESTRICT`, but this does not work on the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be governed by the [`org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PolicyKitPermissions/12.04#org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data) Polkit action:

> - description: Change your own user data
> - message: Authentication is required to change your own user data
> - defaults:
>
>   - `allow_active`: `yes`
>   - `allow_any`: `no`
>   - `allow_inactive`: `no`

You can set it by creating a `.pkla` file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` (say `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/99-nochangedetails.pkla`) containing:

```
[Disable account detail change]
Identity=*
Action=org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data
ResultAny=no
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
```

A related action, [`org.freedesktop.accounts.user-administration`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PolicyKitPermissions/12.04#org.freedesktop.accounts.user-administration) has been overriden by implementation-specific ones (`org.gnome.controlcenter.user-accounts.administration` and `com.canonical.controlcenter.user-accounts.administration`), so it is possible this one has been overriden as well. However, I couldn't find anything similar to `change-own-user-data` in `org.gnome.controlcenter.user-accounts` or `com.canonical.controlcenter.user-accounts`.

Comment: This works, thanks! I did use `ResultInactive=no` in stead of `ResultInctive=no`, guess this was a spelling error?

Comment: @DriesSw indeed it was! sorry.